# NP-hardness of MCSP

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, circuits

[*Ryan Williams and Cody Murray*](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2015/5074/pdf/26.pdf) in 2015 proved that MCSP (Minimum Circuit Size Problem) is provably not NP-hard under local reductions. (Local reductions are the ones in which you are allowed time $O(n^{1/2} - \epsilon))$. He has done it by showing even stronger statement that: Even Parity can't reduced to MCSP using local reductions. In the same paper, he has mentioned in footnotes that "Dhiraj Holden and Chris Umans (personal communication) proved independently that there is no TIME(poly(logn)) reduction from SAT to MCSP unless NEXP $\subseteq \Sigma_{2}^{P}$".

The problem is: $TIME(poly(log n))$ is much smaller than $O(n^{1/2} - \epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon$. (Since you are allowed only poly(log n) time to calculate each bit of output instead of $O(n^{1/2} - \epsilon)$). So, If MCSP is not locally hard(unconditionally), then how come under the much stricter reduction $TIME(poly(log n))$, it is still possible to prove MCSP is NP-hard?

Comment: Please include links to the papers you mention. The first one, by the way, has a coauthor, Cody D. Murray.

Comment: What's MCSP?  Can you spell out the acronym?  Can you provide a full citation to all papers you  refer to (authors, title, where published, and link to freely available pdf, if available)?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sure. It was an honest mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: @D.W. MCSP is Minimum Circuit Size Problem.  we are given (T,k)
where T is truth-table of a boolean function and k is a positive integer (encoded in binary or unary), and the
goal is to determine if T is the truth table of a Boolean function with circuit complexity at most k. The links to the papers have been updated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footnote mentions an earlier unpublished result which is superseded by a result proved in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

The reductions considered by [Murray and Williams](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2015/5074/pdf/26.pdf) are *local*: each bit of the output can be computed in time $O(n^{1/2-\epsilon})$ (on a RAM). In contrast, [Allender et al.](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/papers/oracleMCSP-stacs.pdf) consider logspace reductions, in which each bit can be computed in logarithmic space. The latter notion of reductions is stronger since an algorithm running in space $C\log n$ could run in time $n^C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant (which could be larger than 1/2).

Comment: Yes. Correct. But In Murray, Williams paper cited above on page 368, they have mentioned in Footnotes the following: Dhiraj Holden and Chris Umans (personal communication) proved independently that there is no TIME(poly(logn)) reduction from SAT to MCSP unless $NEXP \subseteq \Sigma_{2}^{P}$. The proof is not given, but can be easily done. Start with succ. SAT and use TIME(poly(logn)) to reduce to succ. MCSP, which implies NEXP collapses to $\Sigma_{2}^{P}$. This is where the problem lies. TIME(poly(logn)) is surely stricter reduction than Local reduction and is yet not ruled out.

Comment: Al algorithm running in polylogarithmic time doesn't necessarily use only logarithmic space.

Comment: Agreed sir. But, the ultimate question remains. In Murray, Williams paper, Local reductions are ruled out, but TIME(poly(log n)) reductions are not. (as written in the footnote of page 368). In other words, MCSP are not NP-hard under local reductions while they still could be NP-hard under TIME(poly(log n)) reductions. Now, this is the part I am stuck in. Local reductions allows more time for each output bit than TIME(poly(log n)) reductions. So, how is that possible?

Comment: Theorem 1.2 in Murray & Williams is about reductions from PARITY, not NP-hardness reductions. Can you state clearly which two statements you find conflicting?

Comment: Sure sir. On page 368: Theorem 1.2 says that PARITY can't be reduced to MCSP under local reductions. (which means that MCSP is not $AC^{0}[2]$ hard under local reductions) Now, in the footnotes on the same page on 368, it is said that If MCSP is NP-hard under TIME(poly(log n)) reductions, then NEXP $\subseteq \Sigma_{2}^{P}$. My confusion is: If MCSP is not $AC^{0}[2]$ hard under local reduction, then surely it is not NP hard under local reduction too. (Since $AC^{0}[2] \subset NP$ )Still, it is possible to prove MCSP is NP-hard under TIME(poly(log n)) reductions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your post to include this information. Clearly indicate which two statements seem contradictory, and why.

Comment: Yes sir. I have done it. Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: Is your problem with the footnote? If so, it could be that Theorem 1.2 supersedes the footnote. In other words, it could be a strictly stronger result.

Comment: Oh. Then it is good sir. So, I am assuming the current state of knowledge is: "MCSP is provably not NP-hard under local reductions". Any reduction more powerful than that, it is still possible to prove the NP-hardness. Thank you so much.